# ros2 galactic package with custom lib inside returns undefined reference

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i try to build a ros2 galactic package with code from waveshare ad/da raspberry pi hat (https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/High-Precision_AD/DA_Board) .  The package and lib compiles, but it does not link, it returns undefined reference

```
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/ADS1256.dir/src/ADS1256.c.o
[ 60%] Linking C shared library libADS1256.so
[ 60%] Built target ADS1256
Scanning dependencies of target ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/src/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/src/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp.o: in function `WaveshareAdcPublisher::WaveshareAdcPublisher()':
ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC2Ev[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC5Ev]+0x2de): undefined reference to `DEV_ModuleInit()'
/usr/bin/ld: ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC2Ev[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC5Ev]+0x2e3): undefined reference to `ADS1256_init()'
/usr/bin/ld: ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC2Ev[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC5Ev]+0x2f5): undefined reference to `DEV_ModuleExit()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/src/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp.o: in function `WaveshareAdcPublisher::timer_callback()':
ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisher14timer_callbackEv[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisher14timer_callbackEv]+0x4d): undefined reference to `ADS1256_GetAll(unsigned int*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/build.make:138: ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:80: CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Failed   <<< ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc [9.83s, exited with code 2]
```

What do i miss in my CMakeLists.txt file that it could build ? My CMakeLists.txt file and code is here: https://github.com/flobotics/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

thanks in advance
flo

---

Edit:

i put the .c files into a separate ros2 lib package and in my package i do e.g. find_package() and it does find it

```
-- Found ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib: 0.0.0 (/home/ros2/dev_ws/install/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib/share/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib/cmake)
```

i use

```
ament_target_dependencies(ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node
                            rclcpp 
                            std_msgs 
                            ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_interfaces
                            ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib
                            )
```

but then i get:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.dir/src/ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp.o: in function `WaveshareAdcPublisher::WaveshareAdcPublisher()':
ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC2Ev[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC5Ev]+0x2de): undefined reference to `DEV_ModuleInit()'
/usr/bin/ld: ros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_node.cpp:(.text._ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC2Ev[_ZN21WaveshareAdcPublisherC5Ev]+0x2e3): undefined reference to `ADS1256_init()'
```

i read many, also https://answers.ros.org/question/350976/using-ament_cmake-to-build-and-use-a-shared-library/

but also that does not work ??

---

Edit 2: if i use   colcon --log-level=10 build   i can see that there is no "-lros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib" for the linker, and so the linker returns  undefined reference.  I testet the ros2-build lib with a test main.c file, and only when i miss "-lros2_galactic_waveshare_adc_lib" in my gcc build command, it returns undefined reference.

How do i add a compiler or linker option?

add_compile_option() does not seem to work?

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381819/ros2-galactic-package-with-custom-lib-inside-returns-undefined-reference/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2021-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't this just a regular `C++ mangles C symbols but the library exports non-mangled symbols` problem?

Is the waveshare lib plain C, or does it use C++? If the former, you need to enclose the `#include`s of the waveshare's headers with `extern "C" { ... }`, to prevent the C++ compiler from mangling all the function names and the linker then not being able to find them in the library.

Note: this is not special or specific to ROS 2, it's always a problem when linking C with C++.

See #q227146 and #q381206 for similar issues.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2021-07-09**:
hi,
thanks for your answer. I got it working.  Yes your right, its C++ name mangling and using extern "C" removes these errors.

the big thing for me was wiringPi, for use with ubuntu-20.04 and raspberry pi 4. Its solved with installing sudo apt install ibwiringpi-dev  and in CMakeLists.txt adding

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -lpthread -lm -lwiringPi)
endif()

target_link_libraries(my_node wiringPi)

I also wrote a tutorial about it, perhaps it gets merged into ros_documentation.

thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-10**:\

> and in CMakeLists.txt adding
>
> if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang") add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -lpthread -lm -lwiringPi) endif()

That's not really the "CMake way" and I doubt it'd be accepted into `ros2_documentation`.

Perhaps an `IMPORTED` library would be better, or a `Find...cmake` script.

> target_link_libraries(my_node wiringPi)

If you're already linking with `-lwiringPi`, why link it here again?

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2021-07-10**:
I tested it, without target_link_libraries() it returns undefined references to e.g. digitalWrite(), a function from wiringPi lib.  Its perhaps not the cmake way, but the official ROS 2 documentation also uses target_link_libraries  https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_documentation/galactic/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#adding-dependencies

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-10**:
Linking libraries using `add_compile_options(..)` is not something you should do.

`target_link_libraries(..)` *is* what you should use.

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2021-07-11**:
but using add_compile_options() is also recommended by official ROS 2 documentation. https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#compiler-and-linker-options   states :

it is at the moment recommended to use the directory level function add_compile_options(-Wall) to not clutter the code with target-based compile options for all executables and tests.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-11**:
You're *linking libraries* using `add_compile_options(..)`. That's not what it's for.

The "ROS 2 documentation" also doesn't recommend that. It states that `add_compile_options(..)` should be used at directory level *if you're going to use `add_compile_options(..)` for what it is intended in the first place*.

If you don't believe me, try searching for whether `add_compile_options(..)` should be used for linking, and don't limit yourself to ROS or ROS 2.